# Custom style for Data Item

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, gridview

I want to define `Style` or `Template` for `GridView` to easy set type of ItemTemplate, instead of copy-paste many lines of code every time into `<GridView.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate></></>`.

Template consists of `Grid` and binding values.

The next next step will be customize `GridView`, by change style in some of the elements.

Can you give me some hints, because I have problem with it.

Now this looks like:

```
    <GridView
        x:Name="XSessionsView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Sessions}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource stlol}"
        ItemClick="GoToSessionPage_ItemClick">


        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="185" Height="85" x:Name="XProblem"
                              Margin="10 5 5 10">
                <StackPanel Margin="0 5 5 0"
                                        Background="{StaticResource EkSessionBrush}">
                    <TextBlock Margin="10" FontSize="10">
                                    <Run Text="{Binding StartTimeString}"></Run>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5 10 0 0" FontSize="16"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                    <Run Text="{Binding Name}"></Run>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Margin="5 0 5 5" FontSize="10"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <Run Text="{Binding DurationTimeString}"></Run>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
                <Rectangle
                                Width="80" Height="40"
                                Margin="0 5 5 0"
                                Fill="Black" Opacity="0.3"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                Width="80" Height="40"
                                Margin="0"
                                Background="{StaticResource EkSessionCorrespondBrush}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Viewbox VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                         Margin="0"
                                             Height="Auto">
                        <TextBlock Margin="5">
                                    <Run Text="{Binding SessionAttendance}"/>
                                    <Run Text=" users"
                                         FontSize="10"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Viewbox>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

I want to throw `XProblem` element out of the `GridView`.